# DHCP request on ethernet cable reconnect with Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: dhcp, ubuntu-16.04, cable, reconnect

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Server here.

My Ethernet interface is configured to use DHCP via /etc/network/interfaces and also I enabled "allow-hotplug" for the interface. It works. I can boot without cable connected and then plug it in and the interface will be properly configured via DHCP.

Now I want to plug the other end of the cable to another socket of a different network also with DHCP. When I do so I see in dmesg it detects link up/down events but no DHCP discovery requests sent and correspondingly IP address is not changed what basically breaks network access to my device and forces me to manually start dhcp client.

How can I configure my system to rerequest DHCP on cable reconnection?

**UPDATE:**
The easiest solution was to use **netplugd**. Doing this by native means is too complicated.

Comment: I know this is an old entry but it still seems to be valid, check this out: https://asleepfromday.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/udev-and-allow-hotplug-on-ubuntu-and-debian/ Basically, you have to create your own udev-rule

Comment: @Broco, looks interesting. I'll check if it's still applicable to this Ubuntu version. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution in your question, post it as an answer instead. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept it.